# BI Semantic Model Connection in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am working with SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server 2012(Build 1103).

I am able to successfully setup and run everything but for some reason BI semantic model connection is not working. As soon as I save it, i get a message "Sorry, Something went wrong". I have verified that the service account has admin privileges on the Tabular instance of the SSAS. I am not able decipher the ULS Logs. It fails in a split second. I have checked SQL Server Profiler and the activity is not even registered.

> Fetching app info failed:
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchServiceNotFoundException:
>   The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service.     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.GetProxy(SPServiceContext
>   ServiceContext)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchCommon.GetSearchCenterUrl()
>
> Application error when access /_layouts/15/PowerPivot/ASLinkFile.aspx,
>   Error=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.ASLinkFilePage.ValidateConnectivity(Object
>   source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator.OnServerValidate(String
>   value)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.Validate()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.Validate()     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: I'm going to be trying this today (I hope), did you solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try start "SharePoint Server Search 15" in Services, if it stopped

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.SE! Have you any proof that this action has worked before, for you or anyone else? If you do, please edit your answer and add further explaination